# Resolved - Symfony handle form with passed repository into it

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

**@UPDATE BELOW**

I have read https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html and it works flawlessly with an example show in this doc. Right now I want to do it in reverse (Part->Ticket - Render parts with ticket data)

I'd like to be able to update data of multiple forms and then submit it with one button. In this case each part is separate form.
Right now all I achieved is to put multiple formView() into an array an then render it - it has data from database but those are different forms :(.

The main problem is that when I create new form **PartColletionType** and pass there multiple part objects it does not render it on page but I can add new **PartsType** forms. I assume that the problem is either with relations (ManyToOne - Each part can have only one ticket) or with 'data_class' of PartCollectionType.

Ticket.php

```
#[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'ticket', targetEntity: Part::class , cascade: ['persist'])]
private Collection $parts;
```

Part.php

```
#[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'parts')]
private ?Ticket $ticket = null;
```

As I understand this is a form which contains other forms so I should be able to submit every child form in with button "UpdateAllParts" and Doctrine will do rest of the job

```
class PartColletionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('UpdateAllParts' , SubmitType::class , [])
            ->add('partsType' , CollectionType::class , [
                'entry_type' => PartsType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'mapped' => false,
                'allow_delete' => true
                ]);;
}
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            //I dont know if I have to set there data_class if yes which type?
            // 'data_class' => null,
            // 'data_class' => PartsType::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

```
class PartsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('submit' , SubmitType::class , [])
            ->add('partNumber' , TextType::class , [])
            ->add('distribution' , TextType::class , [])
            ->add('upsTrack' , TextType::class , [])
            ->add('returnalbe' , TextType::class , [])
            ->add('sendDate' , DateType::class , [])
            ->add('SOID' , TextType::class , [])
            //It's a form to display additional Part's Ticket data
            ->add('ticket' , TicketPartType::class , [
            ]);
 }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Part::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Additional for part:

```
class TicketPartType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('Institution')
            ->add('productName')
            ->add('productSerialNumber')
            ->add('externalTicketID')
            ->add('realisationTechnican' , EntityType::class , [
                'mapped' => true,
                'class' => Technican::class,
                'choice_label' => function (Technican $t): string {
                    return $t->getTechnicanSurname() . ' ' . $t->getCity();
                }]);
}
```

In controller I pass multiple tickets

```
$parts = $doctrine->getRepository(Part::class)->findAll();
$parts = $formFactory->createNamed('ticketsparts' , PartColletionType::class , $parts);
        
return $this->renderForm('mba/ticketparts.html.twig' , ['parts' => $parts ]);
```

This is my twig template

```
{% macro printPartForm(partsType , productSerialNumber) %}
{{form(partsType)}}
{% endmacro %}
{% import _self as formMacros %}

<div class="parts0 row g-0" style="background:#CCC;"
data-index="{{ parts.partsType|length > 0 ? p.parts|last.vars.name + 1 : 0 }}"
data-prototype='{{ formMacros.printPartForm(parts.partsType.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}'> 
    
    {% for part in parts.partsType %}
    <div class="row part" >
        {{ formMacros.printPartForm(part)}}
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

</div>
```

**update**
So for now I set **PartColletionType** data class to:

`'data_class' => PartRepository::class`

Then passed Part repository to form

```
    $parts = $formFactory->createNamed('ticketsparts' , PartColletionType::class , $doctrine->getRepository(Part::class));
```

Right now in twig I can access desired entities by calling method on passed paramaeter passed to TWIG ('parts') and everything renders proprely.

```
{% form_theme parts 'bootstrap_5_layout.html.twig' %}
{{form_start(parts, {'attr': {'class':''}}) }}
{{form_row(parts.field_name)}}
{% for item in parts.findByExampleField %}  
<div class="row bg-warning m-5 ">
    <div class="div col-1 ps-2 pe-2 bg-warning">{{form_row(item.ticket.id)}}</div>
    <div class="div col-2 ps-2 pe-2 bg-warning">{{form_row(item.ticket.externalTicketID)}}</div>
    <div class="div col-1 ps-2 pe-2 bg-warning">{{form_row(item.returnalbe)}}</div>
    <div class="div col-1 ps-2 pe-2 bg-warning">{{form_row(item.sendDate)}}</div>
    <div class="div col-1 ps-2 pe-2 bg-warning">{{form_row(item.SOID)}}</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{{form_end(parts)}}
```

Now the question is how to handle it in good fasion?

**@Edit2**
ok... It was ease :0

```
    if(isset($_POST['ticketsparts'])){
        $parts->handleRequest($request);

        if($parts->isSubmitted() && $parts->isValid()){
            var_dump('submitted and valid');
            $submittedParts= $parts->get('findByExampleField')->getData();

            foreach($submittedParts as $c){

                $doctrine->getManager()->persist($c);
            }
            $doctrine->getManager()->flush();
        }
    }
```

Isn't it messy resolution? How much does it influence on performance considering that we pass repository to twig. In my case "selectByExampleField" is going to be limited to ~100 entities so probably it will not be a problem but everytime editing single object makes sending whole data...

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

So... Resolution above is... bad. You cant control what you want to display.
So lets say - for every sort direction you have to make separate form..

Maybe someone will find this useful. Changes I made below, rest of the code is same as above.

It does render multiple forms - single part with assosiated Ticket data to it and with one click I can submit mulitple parts at one. So it's better than ealier.

//Controller.php

```
    $collection_data = $doctrine->getRepository(Part::class)->findAll();
    $form = $this->createForm(PartColletionType::class , null , ['collection_data' => $collection_data]);
    
    if(isset($_POST['part_colletion'])){
        if(isset($_POST['part_colletion']['unsent']))
        {
            $collection_data = $doctrine->getRepository(Part::class)->findUnsentParts();
            $form = $this->createForm(PartColletionType::class , null , ['collection_data' => $collection_data]); 
            return $this->renderForm('mba/ticketparts.html.twig' , ['parts' => $form ]);
        }
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $czesci = $form->get('collection')->getData();
            foreach($czesci as $c){
                $doctrine->getManager()->persist($c);
            }
            $doctrine->getManager()->flush();
        }
    } 
    return $this->renderForm('mba/ticketparts.html.twig' , ['parts' => $form ]);
}
```

//PartColletionType.php

```
class PartColletionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('submit' , SubmitType::class , [ 
                'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-success']])
            ->add('collection' , CollectionType::class , [
                'entry_type' => PartsType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'mapped' => false,
                'data' => $options['collection_data'],
                ]);
;
    }
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => null,
            'collection_data' => null
        ]);
        $resolver->setAllowedTypes('collection_data', 'array');
    }
}
```

```
{% form_theme parts 'bootstrap_5_layout.html.twig' %}
{{form_start(parts, {'attr': {'class':''}}) }}
{{form_row(parts.submit)}}
{% for item in parts.collection %}  
<div class="row  m-5   {% if item.sendDate.vars.value is empty%}bg-danger {%else%} bg-success {% endif %}">
    <div class="div col-1 ps-2 pe-2">{{form_row(item.ticket.id)}}</div>
    <div class="div col-2 ps-2 pe-2">{{form_row(item.ticket.externalTicketID)}}</div>
    <div class="div col-1 ps-2 pe-2">{{form_row(item.sendDate)}}</div>
    <div class="div col-1 ps-2 pe-2">{{form_row(item.SOID)}}</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{{form_end(parts)}}
```